# Cluster points of log canonical thresholds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $B_n(0)$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$. How can we construct a plurisubharmonic function $\varphi$ (resp. a graded sequence of coherent ideal sheaves $\frak{a}_{\bullet}=\{a\it_{k}\}$) on $B_n(0)$ such that the log canonical threshold $\text{LCT}_0(\varphi)=1$ (resp. $\text{LCT}_0(\frak{a}_{\bullet})=\rm\text{1}$), and for any open neighborhood $U\subset\subset B_n(0)$ of the origin, there is a point $x\in U$ satisfying $\text{LCT}_x(\varphi)<1$ (resp. $\text{LCT}_x(\frak{a}_{\bullet})<\rm1$)?

Comment: lct is a lower semicontinuous function.

Comment: Yes, but it seems not to be enough for this question.